# post form data using ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

i have the following form:

```
<form name="register" id="register" action="include/process_registration.php" method="post"> 
<div class="form_error">Ooops! There is some missing or incorrect information. Please look back over this section. </div>    

<div class="left_form2" >
<div class="inner_form1">
<p>Your First Name:*</p>
<p>Your Last Name:*</p>
<p>Date of Birth:*</p>
</div>
<div class="inner_form2">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="login_form2" autocomplete="off"><br/>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="login_form2" autocomplete="off"><br/>  
<input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" class="login_form2"><br/>
</div>    
</div>


<div class="left_form2" style="text-align:right;">
<div class="inner_form1">
<p>Email Address:*</p>
<p>Confirm Email:*</p>
</div>
<div class="inner_form2">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="login_form2" autocomplete="off"><br/>
<input type="text" name="email2" id="email2" class="login_form2" autocomplete="off"><br/>  
</div>
</div>



<input type="submit" id="register1" name="register" value="Register" class="buttons_register"> 
</form>
```

i am then using ajax to post my form data to my mysql query process_registration.php:

Ajax:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
//alert('Document is ready');

                $('#register1').click(function() {
                    var a = $('#firstname').html();
                    var b = $('#lastname').html();
                    var c = $('#dob').html();
                    var d = $('#email').html();
                    var f = $('#email2').html();
//alert('You picked: ' + sel_stud);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "include/process_registration.php",
                        data: {theOption: a, theOption2: b, theOption3: c, theOption4: d, theOption5: f},
                        success: function(whatigot) {
//alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);
                            $('#LaDIV').html(whatigot);
                            $('#theButton').click(function() {
                                alert('You clicked the button');
                            });
                        } //END success fn
                    }); //END $.ajax
                }); //END dropdown change event
            }); //END document.ready
        </script>
```

my php file process_registration which contains my mysql query looks like so:

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    include("config.php");
    include("verify.php");
    //retrieve our data from POST

    $firstname = $_POST['theOption'];
    $lastname = $_POST['theOption2'];
    $dob = $_POST['theOption3'];
    $email = $_POST['theOption4'];
    $email2 = $_POST['theOption5'];


    $firstname = stripslashes($firstname);
    $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($firstname);
    $lastname = stripslashes($lastname);
    $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);
    $email = stripslashes($email);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $email2 = stripslashes($email2);
    $email2 = mysql_real_escape_string($email2);
    $dob = stripslashes($dob);
    $dob = mysql_real_escape_string($dob);

    include '../dependables/secure.php';  

    $sql = "INSERT INTO supplier_registration (id, first_name, last_name, supplier_email, supplier_password, salt, dob, date) VALUES ('', '$firstname','$lastname','$email2', '$hash', '$salt', '$dob', now())";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql);


    ?>
```

for some reason i am getting taken to the process_registation.php page on the form submit and getting undefined index errors for all my form values. Can someone please show me where i am going wrong? Thanks

Comment: that's because your `$('#register1')` is `type='submit'` , so by pressing it you actually submit... try changing to `type='button'` :)

Comment: @user3012759 thanks i tried that but now nothing happens at all the button becomes unresponsive

Comment: @user3012759 the button is fine how is is, its just because the form is submitting as it would normally, you need to prevent that in the JS

Comment: you sure your ajax call does not happen? can you try to add the debug in your js again and see how far you get?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: The way you're storing the password salt separately is also extremely worrying. Please use [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to that page because the action of the form says it.

You can prevent that with javascript/jquery when submiting the form and then do the ajax code.

```
$("#register1").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //rest of your code
});
```

Also you won't get the inputs values with `.html()`, should use `.val()`

PS: you can get less code with `serialize` function for your forms. Take a look on jQuery API.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your form...

```
action="include/process_registration.php"
```

Just make it action="" if you want it to reload the current page.

You might want to actually echo something from your process_registration.php too, otherwise the "whatigot" from the success function will always be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the submit click working as it is usually expected to.

You also need to use `.val()` instead of `.html()` as you should be getting the value of the input and not the html within the input.

```
$('#register1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $('#firstname').val();
    var b = $('#lastname').val();
    var c = $('#dob').val();
    var d = $('#email').val();
    var f = $('#email2').val();

    // AJAX Call
});
```